# Updating object `A` when object `B` is changed - Android programming

Tags: java, android, oop, arraylist, android-edittext

I have two classes that hold a bunch of data that the user inputs and specifies.

Class `A` has several parameters, and one of it's parameters is it gets assigned an instance of class `B`.

Now, both class `A` and `B`'s values are able to be edited at any moment in Android by clicking on the object's reference inside of a `ListView`, via a custom built `dialog` that appears with editable forms.

Now when I am constructing class `A`, a dialog box pops up and asks me to fill out a `name string`, a `int color` and assign an instance of class from a `Spinner` `B` that was created and stored in an `ArrayList`.

My problem lies in that if I click on class `B` and change one of it's parameters; for instance it's `string name` or `string phoneNum`; I need to be able to update any instances of class `A` that use that edited instance of class `B` with the new class that is changed.

I guess I am confused on what a good way is to check and see if class `B` is being used by any of class `A`...

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is a bit convoluted and difficult to understand. Try improving it with some simple code that offers the bare minimum needed to display the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Seems like a job for the observer pattern.

Comment: @fabian my thoughts exactly. Otherwise, for simplicity, simply iterate all `A` objects and let them inspect the status of the related `B` object every time a `B` is changed. Ineffective but simple.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; is there any good code examples of an observer pattern implemented in Android that I can check out @fabian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to add a unique identifier to class B so that you can check which objects of class A have objects of B that you care about. For example:

```
public class B {

  private int id;

  private int getId() {
     return id;
  }
}
```

You should set the value of "id" in its constructor in a way that each instance of B would have a unique id. Then in your list of A's, you could just do this:

```
for (A a : listOfAs) {
  if (a.getB().getId() == theId) {
    // Do something to "a"
  }
}
```

where "theId" is the ID of B that you're currently modifying.